# Creating MSI package with powerbuilder12.5

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

im really new to powerbuilder classics IDE and creating an installer package gives me a hard time. my questions is

1. Does PowerBuilder has a Painter for that specific action?
2. Can I include the PB runtime DLLs in that MSI/Installer file
3. Can i create an installer for PowerBuilder using NSIS? its a really cool installer but i dont know how to compile the PB reference files and suchs.

may you all enlighten me!

notes: i have used incremental build/full build and deploy function in PB but no MSI files has been generated

Answer (score 1):

There is a program PBPACK###.EXE (### = PB version) located in the ...\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder folder. There should have been a shortcut added when PB was installed.

It will create an msi file but only for PowerBuilder runtime files. It will not include your application files.

I use Inno Setup. It only creates install exe, not msi.
http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php